# Limit words in an regex

Tags: regex

How can I limit the words count in this

```
[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}
```

regexp. Allow these characters but only 3 times \s.

This will work for 3 words:

```
(^[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,16}\s[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,16}\s[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,16}$)
```

from 2 to 16 chars long but there must be a shorter way.

Comment: How do you define a *word* ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I guess i could define it by space.I have to validate a city name..Washington is one word but San Diego is 2 words,New York too.If I put \s in the range it will accept s a n d i e g o.

Comment: Off-topic: validating city names (and names in general) with regular expressions is a bad idea. You can find many legit city names that fail your validation, and also many fake names that pass validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!(?:.*? ){3,})[a-z ,.'-]{2,15}$
```

See [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV6pT3/1)

`(?!(?:.*? ){3,})` will ensure that you can't have more than 2 spaces

Answer (score 3):

A little bit shorter:

```
^([A-Za-z,.'-]{2,16}(?:\s[A-Za-z,.'-]{2,16}){2})$
```

or, if your regex flavour support it:

```
^(([A-Za-z,.'-]{2,16})(?:\s(?1)){2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `([A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}\s){3}` if your words are separated with a space.

Or `([A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}(\s|\z)){3}` if exactly three words in string.

Or `\A([A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}(\s|\z)){3}` grab first three words

Or `^([A-Za-z,.'-]{2,15}(\s|\z)){3}$` to be more strict.

Comment: This requires the last word to have a space at the end (e.g. `"ab cd ef "`)